# What is this RGB color map for?

Tags: normal-map, height-map

So I found this coloued map from some game files, It appears to be for highlights or refelction in some way. As the yellow/red areas would be shiny and the lighter blue areas should reflect more light than the darker blue. Other option is that its a height map in some way,but I doubt that as the blue cross on the button would be higher than the button itself.

I am wondering:

1. What type of map is this?
2. How to use this map or at least a point in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it might be a world-space normal map of a texture atlas, but it's hard to tell. The patch around the eye seems "blocky" and out of place for a map like that. Then again, I have no idea what the texture is supposed to look like,

Comment: That might be the case, I have also heard that each colour channel might be a different map, Blue seems to be for height/bump, the red and green might be for roughness and something else. The sharp green area is covered by the button for her eyes. And the buttons are shiny in game.